# how to stop infinite loop when there is no more data (pagination)

Tags: php, jquery, html, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

I need help with this jquery script I'm using in my pagination to create lazy loading/ infinite scroll.

The loading is working, however, it keeps displaying 1 whenever new data is loaded and at the end if there is no more data it keeps load 1 1 1 1 infinitely. I need help in getting rid of the 1 and also stopping the loading if there's no more data from db.

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            var last_id = $(".post-id:last").attr("id");
            loadMoreData(last_id);
        }
    });


    function loadMoreData(last_id){
      $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'LoadingData1.php?last_id=' + last_id,
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $('.ajax-load').show();
                }
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $('.ajax-load').hide();
                $("#load-data").append(data);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                  alert('There's an issue with Loading...');
            });
    }
</script>
```

My LoadingData1.php code

```
<?php
                            $newid = $_GET['last_id'];
                            $not = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM orderinhomeonlinecall WHERE id < ? AND cuid=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10');
                            $not -> bind_param('ii', $newid, $uid);
                            $not -> execute();
                            $result = $not->get_result();       
                            $json = include('data1.php');
                            echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

My data1.php code:

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                                $id1 = $row['id'];
                                $orderId1 = $row['orderId'];
                                $serviceName1 = $row['serviceName'];
                                $totalprice1 = $row['totalprice'];
                                $orderStatus1 = $row['orderStatus'];
?>



                                <a href="booktype/orderdetails.php?orderId=<?php echo $orderId1; ?>" class="post-id" id="<?php echo $id1 ?>">
                                <?php switch ($orderStatus1) {
                                        case 1: ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle color-gray2-dark"></i>
                                    <span><?php echo $serviceName1; ?></span>
                                    <strong><?php echo $ctype1; ?></strong>

                                    <em class="bg-gray2-light font-11">&#8358;<?php echo $totalprice1; ?></em>
                                        <?php break;


                                        case 2:
                                        case 3:
                                        case 4:
                                        case 5:
                                            ?>
                <i class="fa fa-circle color-blue2-dark"></i>
                                    <span><?php echo $serviceName1; ?></span>
                                    <strong><?php echo $ctype1; ?></strong>
                <em class="bg-blue2-light font-11">&#8358;<?php echo $totalprice1; ?></em>
                                        <?php break;
                                        case 6:
                                            ?>
                <i class="fa fa-circle color-green2-dark"></i>
                                    <span><?php echo $serviceName1; ?></span>
                                    <strong><?php echo $ctype1; ?></strong>
                <em class="bg-green2-light font-11">&#8358;<?php echo $totalprice1; ?></em>
                                        <?php break;

                                        case 10:
                                        case 11:
                                            ?>
                <i class="fa fa-circle color-red2-dark"></i>
                                    <span><?php echo $serviceName1; ?></span>
                                    <strong><?php echo $ctype1; ?></strong>
                <em class="bg-red2-light font-11">&#8358;<?php echo $totalprice1; ?></em>
                                            <?php 
                                            break;
                                             } ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                </a>

                                <?php 
                                }
                                        ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change (remove) Json part `$json = include('data1.php'); echo json_encode($json);` to `include('data1.php');`. json code does nothing in your code as I see

Comment: Thanks Dilek. I just did that and the 1s are gone. However, the loop isn't stopping. It keeps looping the already loaded results.

Comment: And there should be a div in loop `<div class="post-id" id="<?php echo $row['last_id']; ?>"> /*do your other things in here*/ </div>` your code should be very simple difficuld to read all that code, I am sorry.

Comment: id="<?php echo $row['last_id']; ?> is making it not load at all. the $id1 is needed to display the row from db. This thing is very tricky, can't seem to find where the problem is.

Comment: last_id was just an example I saw your pots id is id, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comment json code had nothing to do in your php,

in while loop you need to show a class or id to ajax control.

Final solution should look like this:

Your php codes :

```
$newid = $_GET['last_id'];
$not = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM orderinhomeonlinecall WHERE id < ? AND cuid=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10');
$not -> bind_param('ii', $newid, $uid);
$not -> execute();
$result = $not->get_result();       
include('data1.php');
```

Your while loop :

```
<?php 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $id1 = $row['id'];
    $orderId1 = $row['orderId'];
    $serviceName1 = $row['serviceName'];
    $totalprice1 = $row['totalprice'];
    $orderStatus1 = $row['orderStatus'];
?>
```

Your html in loop :

```
<div class="post-id" id="<?php echo $id1; ?>">

  /*Do your other things in here */

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

And ajax codes:

```
loaded = true; //Initialize
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if(($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) && loaded) { //Add in condition
       var last_id = $(".post-id:last").attr("id");
       loadMoreData(last_id);
   }
});

function loadMoreData(last_id){
 loaded = false; //False at start ajax call
 $.ajax({
       url: '/loadMoreData1.php?last_id=' + last_id,
       type: "get",
       beforeSend: function()
       {
           $('.ajax-load').show();
       }
   })
   .done(function(data)
   {
           $('.ajax-load').hide();
           $("#post-data").append(data);
           loaded  = true; //true to load data
   })
   .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
   {
         alert('No response...');
         loaded  = true;
   });
}
```

Example here https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-infinite-scroll-pagination-using-jquery-ajax-exampleexample.html

Comment: url: '/loadMoreData1.php?last_id=' + last_id, doesn't load. It only loads when I replace it with url: 'loadMoreData1.php?last_id=' + last_id.... That's omitting the /. Thanks for the help. It's working fine now

Comment: @LouisWebSolutions its because of u are using `#RewriteBase /` or `<base>` tag, Glad I helped